# Plot graph and include missing value number on bar graph python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

New to python and I do have medical data where I have data based on hosipitals. Now I do want to plot this data per hospital, period it was collected and number of patients, but I do also want to include the number of missing data per hospital on the graph so that I can also know the months data was not entered per hospital. this is a snippet of how my data looks like

```
data = {'Hosp_name':['Hos1', 'Hos1', 'Hos2', 'Hos2','Hos3','Hos3'], 'Period':['20-Apr', '21-Apr', '20-Apr', '21-Aug','20-Apr','21-Apr'],
                                                                             'Num_of_patients':[30,'NAN',45,56,'NAN',67]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

How can I transform this data so that I can plot it right and include missing data on the graph. this is what I tried

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.bar(df, x='Hosp_name', y=['period','Num_of_patients'])
fig.show()
```

Expected output is a bar graph of each hospital showing period data was collected, number of missing value and number of patients

Comment: Please, provide a minimal runnable example. Where does `c` come from? Fix your quotes.
What is the expected output? One column for each (hospital, period) pair? How do you want to display the missing values?

Comment: @AlexisBRENON the code is wrong though my expected output is each hospital to have its own bar graph and having a count of missing values per hospital and display them on graph

Comment: This will be a little bit tricky as the number of patients and the number of missing values are not in the same "unit". Imagine an hospital with 1 million patients on a period and a NAN on the second. Plotting both values on the same plots will make the count of missing values too small... You should probably play with [a second Y axis](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/two_scales.html), or maybe to plot them on two different axes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version, how i understand it and how it would be with matplotlib

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Hosp_name':['Hos1', 'Hos1', 'Hos2', 'Hos2','Hos3','Hos3'], 'Period':['20-Apr', '21-Apr', '20-Apr', '21-Aug','20-Apr','21-Apr'], 'Num_of_patients':[30,'NAN',45,56,'NAN',67]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data).groupby(['Period','Hosp_name'])[['Num_of_patients']].sum()#.reset_index().set_index('Period')
df['Num_of_patients'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Num_of_patients'], errors = 'coerce')

Out[1]:

                        Num_of_patients
    Period  Hosp_name   
    20-Apr  Hos1       30.0
            Hos2       45.0
            Hos3       NaN
    21-Apr  Hos1       NaN
            Hos3       67.0
    21-Aug  Hos2       56.0

df1 = df.pivot_table(index = 'Period', values = 'Num_of_patients', columns = 'Hosp_name').fillna(0) 
df1

Out[2]:

    Hosp_name   Hos1    Hos2    Hos3
    Period          
    20-Apr      30.0    45.0    0.0
    21-Apr      0.0     0.0    67.0
    21-Aug      0.0     56.0    0.0


df1 = df1.reset_index()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

for i,col in enumerate(df1.columns[1:]):
    bars= plt.bar([x+i*0.3 for x in list(df1.index)], df1[col], width = 0.3, label = col)

    for bar in bars:
        plt.gca().text(bar.get_x() + bar.get_width()/2, bar.get_height() - 5, str(int(bar.get_height())),ha='center', color='w', fontsize=11)

plt.xticks(list(df1.index), df1['Period'])
plt.legend()
```

[image]

### for set of columns

```
data = {'Hosp_name':['Hos1', 'Hos1', 'Hos2', 'Hos2','Hos3','Hos3'],'Period':['20-Apr', '21-Apr', '20-Apr', '21-Aug','20-Apr','21-Apr'], 'Num_of_patients':[30,'NAN',45,56,'NAN',67],'age':[11,21,31,36,26,16], 'patient_visits':[20,30,40,50,60,10]} 

# i don't know your case, but i can't imagine the reasin for sum(age), so i evaluate the mean(age)

df = pd.DataFrame(data).groupby(['Period','Hosp_name'])[['Num_of_patients','age','patient_visits']].agg({'Num_of_patients': 'sum', 'patient_visits': 'sum', 'age':'mean'}) 

df['Num_of_patients'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Num_of_patients'], errors = 'coerce')

df
Out[10]:

                   Num_of_patients  patient_visits  age
    Period      Hosp_name           
    20-Apr      Hos1      30.0      20              11
                Hos2      45.0      40              31
                Hos3      NaN       60              26
    21-Apr      Hos1      NaN       30              21 
                Hos3      67.0      10              16
    21-Aug      Hos2      56.0      50              36


df1 = df.pivot_table(index = 'Period', values = 'Num_of_patients','patient_visits','age'], columns = 'Hosp_name').fillna(0)
df1 = df1.reset_index()
df1

Out[11]:

                Period  Num_of_patients         age                   patient_visits
       Hosp_name        Hos1    Hos2    Hos3    Hos1    Hos2    Hos3    Hos1    Hos2    Hos3
           0    20-Apr  30.0    45.0    0.0     11.0    31.0    26.0    20.0    40.0    60.0
           1    21-Apr  0.0     0.0     67.0    21.0    0.0     16.0    30.0    0.0     10.0
           2    21-Aug  0.0     56.0    0.0      0.0    36.0    0.0       0.0   50.0    0.0
```

#### Here is full code for visualization (Different graph for metrics)

And you able to do visualization whatever you want.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

level_1 = ['Num_of_patients', 'age', 'patient_visits']
level_2 = ['Hos1', 'Hos2', 'Hos3']

color = ['r','g','b']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,1, sharex = True, gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0.3}, figsize=(10,5))


for i, metric in enumerate(level_1):
    for j, hosp in enumerate(level_2):

        bars = ax[i].bar([x+j*0.2 for x in list(df1.index)], df1[(metric, hosp)], width = 0.2, color = color[j], label = hosp)       

        for bar in bars:
                ax[i].text(bar.get_x() + bar.get_width()/2, bar.get_height() - 8, str(int(bar.get_height())), 
                         ha='center', color='w', fontsize=8)

    ax[i].set_title(f'{metric}', loc = 'right')
    ax[i].legend()


plt.xticks(list(df1.index), df1['Period'])
```

[image]

#### Different graph for Hosps

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

level_1 = ['Hos1', 'Hos2', 'Hos3']
level_2 = ['Num_of_patients', 'age', 'patient_visits']

color = ['r','g','b']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,1, sharex = True, gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0.3}, figsize=(5,5))

for i, hosp in enumerate(level_1):
    for j, metric in enumerate(level_2):

        bars = ax[i].bar([x+j*0.2 for x in list(df1.index)], df1[(metric, hosp)], width = 0.2, color = color[j], label = metric)       

        for bar in bars:
                ax[i].text(bar.get_x() + bar.get_width()/2, bar.get_height() - 8, str(int(bar.get_height())), 
                         ha='center', color='w', fontsize=8)

    ax[i].set_title(f'{metric}', loc = 'right')
    ax[i].legend()


_ = plt.xticks(list(df1.index), df1['Period'])
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to use more columns in your code,I have more columns to be included with num of patients column. If it's possible how can add them

Comment: as i can see, it's already has ability to work with additional columns. May be the only adaptation would be in loop, to point on exactli columns name (df1.columns[1:]. here it is, for examlpe put ['Hos1','Hos2']) and change the koefficient of width (not 0.3 but 1/number of columns)

Comment: am adding columns at this level [['Num_of_patients']], but if I plot It tells me It cant find all other columns, it just plots with one column in there

Comment: you mean structure like this?
 data = {'Hosp_name':[...], 'Period':[...],'Num_of_patients':[...], 'ONE_MORE_COLUMN':[...]}

Comment: I mean like this  pd.DataFrame(data).groupby(['Period','Hosp_name'])[['Num_of_patients','age', 'patient_visits']].sum()

Comment: i have updated code with paid attention on your comment

Comment: Thank you sir, working well though I am stuck at the plotting section. could you finish it up and if possible each hospital to have its own plot differently in a facet grid

Comment: have update, now it full has code for visualization

Comment: Just slight thing I am having this error     name 'color' is not defined   at the color section

Comment: I am not sure why I am getting an index out of range error. in my case, level_2 which are hospital names are about 18 hospital names. Then how can I have all these 18 graphs of 18 hospital names separately as subplots

Comment: sorry just noticed your output are graphs based on column names num_of_patients, age, and patient_visits. I don't want it to be this way, I want the graphs per hospitals, graph for Hosp1, Hosp2, Hosp3 and that is x-axis should be period against others

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201555/discussion-between-alexey-and-livingstonem).

Answer (score 0):

Much easier way here:

df['column'].value_counts(dropna=False).plot(kind='bar')